# Angular5 [Select+Option]: how to use complex data?

Tags: html, angular

For some reason I have a complex data in the **app.component.ts** file:

```
export class AppComponentimplements OnInit {

    tests = {
        'name': 'Bob',
        'grade': '5th',
        'score': [
            ['math',    'A',   'A+',  'A-'],
            ['english', 'B',   'B-',  'A'],
            ['french',  'A',   'A+',  'A'],
            ['chem',    'C',   'C',   'C'],
            ['sport',   'B',   'B',   'B']
        ]};

}
```

I want to show the 1st items under 'score' into a **select/option** dropdown button.

(These are: ['math', 'english', 'french', 'chem', 'sport'])

In the **app.component.html** file, the following code is one of my many tries. But sadly it does not work.

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let test of tests" [ngValue]="test.score[0]">
        {{test.score[0]}}
    </option>
</select>
```

How could I do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML code is wrong.

Try this.

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let score of tests.score" [ngValue]="tests.score[0]" >
      {{score[0]}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way, you should be able to get **selected value**:

```
<select id='subjects' [formControl]="selectedSubject">
    <option *ngFor="let test of tests.score" [ngValue]="test[0]">
        {{test[0]}}
    </option>
</select>
```

As **[ngValue]** you can use `test` if you want to get selected full array:`['math', 'A',   'A+',  'A-']`:

```
<option *ngFor="let test of tests.score" [ngValue]="test">
            {{test[0]}}
</option>
```

or `test[0]` if you want first value of selected array(ex. `math`):

```
<option *ngFor="let test of tests.score" [ngValue]="test[0]">
                {{test[0]}}
</option>
```

[Code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k9u7d8)

Also don't remember to include `ReactiveFormsModule` into AppModule. If we want to use **Reactive Forms**(formControl/formGroup directive...) as in code example